# Cordova project : Error: Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:parseDebugLocalResources'

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I'm learning of this Cordova for Android app development and following the below document for latest version of Cordova 11.x

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/cli/index.html

When do the requirement check, result as below :

=====
E:\HTML5\Android\hello>cordova requirements android

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 11.0.16
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
No android targets (SDKs) installed!
Gradle: installed E:\MyProgramfiles\gradle-7.5.1\bin\gradle.BAT
Some of requirements check failed

=====

When try to build the Cordova app and hitting error message below :

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: E:\MyProgramfiles\android-sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.
> > E:\MyProgramfiles\android-sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmMpB.png)

Anyone else can pls advise on this ?

Comment: you have no SDKs installed. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#requirements-and-support

Comment: Double checked, and already installed according the doc..

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 11.0.16
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed


E:\HTML5\Android\hello>echo %Android_SDK_ROOT%
E:\MyProgramfiles\android-sdk

E:\HTML5\Android\hello>echo %Android_HOME%
E:\MyProgramfiles\android-sdk

But not sure why it's still complaining "Android target" not installed" !!!

Comment: You have JDK installed. NOT SDK targets..... hence your error of "Android target: not installed" 
 https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#adding-sdk-packages

Comment: @E.Maggini, now have error message : Android target: not installed
Please install the Android SDK Platform "platforms;android-30", But i already installed Android Platform 11 - API level 30 and SDK tool from 29 - 33 version. This is totally crazy..

Comment: While googling the error message, I can see many similar error messages related cordova and couldn't find the answer. This is totally is not a good SDK for android development.....